# can i merge all commits in branch, but only push half without any problems

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push

I would like to merge sandbox branch into stage branch, however i have a few commmits that i dont want pushed after this.

Im not sure how to merge up to only certain changes, and have not yet done a cherrry-pick so i dont to break things at this sensitive time in development.  Therefore i thought i could just go ahead and  merge ALL (which is fine they will all end up there anyway), then push only up to a certain sha.

e.g.

```
git checkout stage  
git merge sandbox
git push <remotename> <SHA for commit 2>:stage
```

this should leave commits 1,2,3 and 4 on sandbox branch, commits 1,2,3,4 on stage branch, and 1,2 only actually pushed to remote stage.

will this work as expected?

Comment: Would `squash`ing them into a single commit satisfy you?

Comment: I would think  `git merge <SHA for commit 2> instead of `git merge sandbox`would be a better choice.  Do that, `git push`, then merge the rest

Comment: ok, i wasnt sure if that was possible, so i can just merge forward a single commit into another branch? i havent done that yet.  Thats perfect, If that works.  If u make that an answer ill probably mark as accepted.